# A regex to allow exactly 5 digit number with one optional white space before and after the number?

Tags: javascript, regex

With the regex in the jQuery code below, I can restrict the input text field to accept only 5 digits but it allows more white spaces before and after the number than just one. I mean to match a 5-digit number that is at the beginning of the string or is preceded by at most one space and is at the end of the string or is followed by at most one space. Please help me refine my regex to meet my requirement.

```
jQuery("input:text[name='address_1[zip]']").change(function(e) {
if (!jQuery(this).val().match(/\b\d{5}\b/g)) { 
        alert("Please enter a valid zip code");
        jQuery("input[name='address_1[zip]']").val("");
        return false;                        
    }        
});
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current regex?

Comment: It allows for more spaces than one

Comment: Do you mean you wish to match a 5-digit number that can be preceded and followed by any character other than a digit but cannot be preceded by two spaces (implying two or more) and cannot be followed by two spaces? Alternatively, maybe you mean that you wish to match a 5-digit number that is at the beginning of the string or is preceded by at most one space and is at the end of the string or is followed by at most one space. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Edited the post. This is exactly what I need "to match a 5-digit number that is at the beginning of the string or is preceded by at most one space and is at the end of the string or is followed by at most one space."

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Also, please let me know some resources online for me to get familiar with Regex.

Comment: I can suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at. Also, see my SO profile for one more resource.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I am looking at some of what you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might suggest just using lookarounds here:

```regex
/(?<![ ]{2})\b\d{5}\b(?![ ]{2})/
```

This pattern says to:

```regex
(?<![ ]{2})  assert that 2 (or more) spaces do NOT precede the ZIP code
\b\d{5}\b    match a 5 digit ZIP code
(?![ ]{2})   assert that 2 (or more) spaces do not follow
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2nERiu/2) showing that the pattern works.

Comment: I tried your regex, it allows for aaa12345. It shouldn't allow this

Comment: @PKTG I have fixed it, please check again.

Comment: Tim, since I'm just copying your code I will lose an opportunity to understand how your regex works. Can I ask you to kindly write a few lines describing it?

Comment: I have already given an explanation.  The lookarounds ensure that 2 spaces cannot precede the ZIP code or follow it.  Other than that, it just matches your original pattern `\b\d{5}\b`.

Comment: Thank you, please direct me to some resources online for me to learn regex.

Comment: I practice regex on this site and at my job.  Here is a great regex site: http://www.rexegg.com

Comment: PKTG, at the link Tim gives you can hover the cursor over each element of the regular expression to obtain an explanation of that element's function.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, I see that. But for someone who wants to learn it from the scratch, going through some tutorial is the best thing to do. I am a naive at regex.

Comment: PKTG, I've not given much thought to effective ways to learn regular expressions, as I've just picked up a bit at a time, mainly from references and SO, as opposed to tutorials. I just Googled "best ways to learn regular expressions" and came up with some interesting hits. regexone.com might be one place to start. Taking a course at a place like udemy.com is another possibility. Regular expressions may initially be a little intimidating, in part because of the unfamiliar syntax. Except for a few advanced features they are actually fairly straightforward...

Comment: ... At some point learning how regex engines work provides valuable insights.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks a lot for these comments. They are inspiring me. I'm not sure if you received my sent after visiting your SO profile. cary@swoveland.com is where I emailed to.

Comment: PKTG, `(?<![ ]{2})` is a *negative lookbehind*. It is a condition that must be satisfied for a match but is not part of the match that is returned. Tim has explained it's purpose. The `\b`'s are *word breaks* (or more accurately, [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). `(?![ ]{2})` is a *negative lookahead*. It's similar to a negative lookbehind except it concerns text that follows the match.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I am still breaking my head to understand negative lookbehind and lookahead 100%.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I decided not to allow even a single whitespace before and after the 5-digit zipcode. Could you please modify the regex? I tried to change as `(?<![ ]{1})\b\d{5}\b(?![ ]{1})` I am sore this can further be simplified.

Comment: ...not sure what you are trying to do now.  If you want to match _only_ a 5 digit ZIP code, then use anchors: `^\d{5}$`.  In any case, I suggest opening a new question.  Few users will be reading this old thread at this point.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the beginning of line and end of line

```
match(\A\s?\d{5}\s?\z/g)
```

This mean:

- \A begin of string
- \s? One optional space
- \d{5} five digits
- \s? One optional space
- \z  end of string

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't working. I checked with https://www.phpliveregex.com/#tab-preg-match

Comment: Then try begin of string instead of begin of line

Comment: could you please explain your regex?

Comment: Rockcat, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do.

```
/^\s?\d{5}\s?$/
```

Here's the pure JavaScript test code. You will have to convert this into JQuery style.

```
let p = /^\s?\d{5}\s?$/
let input = ' 54525 ';
let match = p.test( input );
console.log( match )
```

Comment: No, it isn't working

Comment: What is the purpose of carat symbol in your regex?

Comment: The idea is to check that the whole input string matches the pattern, hence, `^` for the start and `$` for the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks, finally I used a regex close to your when I decided not to allow even whitespaces.

Comment: Sree kumar, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked